# Sum the values of 3 rows and put

Tags: mysql, sum

Please I need help in adding the values of 3 rows in my table and adding the total sum into another row. For example:

I want the sum of values from **row1 to row3** be added to **row4**. I have done a lot and done know how to continue any further

row1|row2|row3|row4

100 |350 |500 |

350 |298 |123 |

999 |234 |277 |

Your kind help is appreciated.

Mike

Comment: Rows or columns? You've _called_ them rows but they look like columns to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT row1, row2, row3, SUM(row1 + row2 + row3) AS row4 FROM table_name;

Answer (score 1):

First, if they *are* actually rows in the database, you can simply create a new row containing the sums:

```
insert into mytable (columnA, columnB, columnC)
    select sum(columnA), sum(columnB), sum(columnC) from mytable
```

But it's rather unusual to do that in the actual table unless you have a way of distinguishing these "totals" rows from the regular ones.

---

If they're *columns,* as appears from the layout, there are some issues.

First, what you're attempting will violate third normal form, which is rarely a good thing. You need to think of what will happen if someone changes one of the columns but *doesn't* also update the totals column.

But, if you *want* to do this, it's a simmple matter of:

```
update mytable set columnD = columnA + columnB + columnC
```

Comment: Or just don'T store the row, either select the sum every time or just create a view. :) No problems with normalizing then. May stillb e bad design though ;)

Comment: @JohannesH, it's the "put" in the title that leads me to believe OP is attempting to place the sum back into the DB somehow.

Comment: According to the comments to my answer he really is. But there is just no reason to do so.

Comment: @Paxadiablo: Your solution worked by adding the values in the table. Thank you so much. However please, how can I save the query in PHPMySQLAdmin so subsequent values will run based on the query?

Comment: @user3201606, no idea how to use that particular tool, I'd suggest asking a separate question.

Comment: @Paxadiablo: I am learning how to create views now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT row1, row2, row3, row1 + row2 + row3 AS row4 FROM wherever;
```

and really - try to solve it on your own and using google first.

Comment: @paxdiablo: its rows. I am summing all values per row and not all values in a colomns.

Comment: Usually one calls one entry in a database "row", while calling all defined fields "columns". (so the way round compared how you do it) That's pretty much standard. Or did I just misunderstand the question?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have applied it but it not updating the row4 wit the total value of the first 3 rows. How can I resolve that?

Comment: I understand. May be I am wrong in my presentation but your approach is still OK though

Comment: don'T ave the row4 at all. Just select it using that query every time. why store it if you can just clculate iut every time? MySQL does cache queries, so don'T worry about that.

Comment: I have spend 5 hours on this query alone

Comment: (if you need it defined somwhere, create a view that uses this query as a base)